# Setting up shared services for projects in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to set up some shared services (e.g. neo4j, MongoDB, and Kafka) in GCP. These services would be used by various applications (separate GCP projects). The services would not be publicly accessible, they should only be network accessible from our other GCP projects in our account. Each application would have a separate database.

My idea is to set up the services within a standalone project (e.g managed-services-prod, managed-services-test), etc. What would be the best way for the applications to access the shared services using GCP?

Comment: when you say 'from the GCP other projects', do you mean other projects within the same organization or other unrelated projects?

Comment: Other projects in our Google account. We don't use organisations as we don't have GSuite or Cloud Identity.

Comment: tbh Google recommends creating organization. It will be much easier to manage all these projects from security, access point of view and some of the feature might require organization node. https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations#organization-node

Comment: To answer your question, creating service accounts for access is one of the best practice

Comment: Can you use a service account to access a database through a client library (e.g. Java app -> neo4j)? I would have thought it would be more like VPC network access or something?

Answer (score 1):

Recapping for better visibility:

1. Google recommends creating organization to manage multiple projects.
2. You can create a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) and grant it access to resources in different project:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_1 \
--member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_2}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/cloudbuild.builds.viewer \
```

You can find more info [here](https://tonym.us/gcp-managing-iam-access-control-across-projects-the-simpler-version.html#gcp-managing-iam-access-control-across-projects-the-simpler-version).